# Bot Framework V4 Azure AD authentication returning bad request

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I had tested authentication by downloading sample from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). I had successfully published to azure after modifiying connection name and able to sign in. However when i started integrating same authentication in my bot application after clicking sign in button am getting bad request for the URL opened in new tab.

Sign In URL displays in page browser when i click sign in button:

https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/login/6e0c3814-3f9f-dc25-5fac-e7e4786b2733_3da58bb0-e03b-9b70-e453?redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftoken.botframework.com%2fapi%2foauth%2fPostSignInCallback%3fsignin%3d921d46120f200e405e44b64bdfa3d847ccd4c38080%26code_challenge%3d

I am not sure whether its right or not but noticed that I am not getting same sign IN URL when i used sample code.

Sign In URL when i used sample:

https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/PostSignInCallback?signin=921d46120f7bde19cfe3ee4747bb5357768f0fa427&code_challenge=&code=12ad14dc96c24220b2c146cd3828d08f

I also added https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/PostSignInCallback under reply URL in Azure AD application.

**Authentication Code: **

```
        Dialogs.Add(Prompt(ConnectionName));
        Dialogs.Add(new ChoicePrompt("choicePrompt"));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("graphDialog", new WaterfallStep[] { PromptStepAsync, ProcessStepAsync }));
```

Note: Currently I am not using any state accessories for authentication and neither using any oauthhelpers. I am just trying to sign in success and get token.

Comment: Can you use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the request and find the inner error message in the response ? A fiddler trace would be helpful to find the exact reason behind this error.

Comment: after entering magic code number back to bot, i am not able to receive token . 
Error: GET /api/usertoken/GetToken
Error Code: 404

In the sample , i did not faced any error.

Comment: Did you configure your redirect URI correctly? It sounds like you're doing everything properly since you're getting an access token. But your ultimate redirection is wrong. Please refer to the article on creating the AAD App Registration : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth#create-your-azure-ad-application